# How can I search and replace guids in Sublime 3

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a textfile where I would like to replace all GUIDs with space.

I want:

```
92094, "970d6c9e-c199-40e3-80ea-14daf1141904"  
91995, "970d6c9e-c199-40e3-80ea-14daf1141904"  
87445, "f17e66ef-b1df-4270-8285-b3c15da366f7"  
87298, "f17e66ef-b1df-4270-8285-b3c15da366f7"  
96713, "3c28e493-015b-4b48-957f-fe3e7acc8412"  
96759, "3c28e493-015b-4b48-957f-fe3e7acc8412"  
94665, "87ac12a3-62ed-4e1d-a1a6-51ae05e01b1a"  
94405, "87ac12a3-62ed-4e1d-a1a6-51ae05e01b1a"
```

To become:

```
92094,
91995,
87445,
87298,
96713,
96759,
94665,
94405,
```

How can i accomplish this in Sublime 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find: `"[\da-f-]{36}"`
- Replace: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- Enable regex mode
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
"           : double quote
  [         : start class character
    \d      : any digit
    a-f     : or letter from a to f
    -       : or a dash
  ]{36}     : end class, 36 characters must be present
"           : double quote
```

**Result for given example:**

```
92094,    
91995,    
87445,    
87298,    
96713,    
96759,    
94665,    
94405,
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing a search for this pattern in regex search mode:

```
"[0-9a-z]{8}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12}"
```

And then just replace with empty string.  This should strip off the GUID, leaving you with the output you want.

### Demo

Comment: I just get Unable to find "[0-9a-z]{8}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{4}-[0-9a-z]{12}"\n I have marked the .* button to enable regular expressions in my search. Anything I do wrong?

Comment: It is working in the demo.  If your lines don't end in `\n`, because of some peculiarity in your data or in Sublime, then try removing `\n` from the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Another regex solution involving a slightly different *search-replace* strategy where we don't care about the GUI format and simply get the first column:

- Search for `([^,]*,).*` (again don't forget to activate the regex mode <kbd>.*</kbd>).
- Replace with `$1`.

#### Details about the regular expression

The idea here is to capture all first columns. A column here is defined by a sequence of

- "some non-comma character": `[^,]*`
- followed by a comma: `[^,]*,`

The first column can then be followed by anything `.*` (the GUI format doesn't matter): `[^,]*,.*`

Finally we need to capture the 1st column using [group capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html): `([^,]*,).*`

In the replace field we use a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `$x` which refers the the *x-th capturing group*.